# How to succesfull read my tcpip connection

Tags: matlab, tcp, read-data

I implemented a few months ago a function that sends data from Matlab to a Weiss WSG50 gripper. This is a Robotic Gripper Tool and uses binary codes as commands. I established a connection with the tcpip function. I wrote my commands and sended them with ´fwrite´ as uint8-data to the gripper. My tcpip object is a client. The gripper a server. The gripper sucessful runs the command perfectly. Until here everthing works as I expected.

The Trouble begins, when I tryied to receive data back from the gripper. The gripper reacts with a awnser message on every sended command (Could be more then one message). But my ´BytesAvailable´ stays empty.

I know that could be diffcult to reproduce, because it may be necessary to have access to the gripper. But eventual I do something basic wrong with setting up the TCPIP object. I tryied already to use ´tcpclient´ but with this function sending is not working also.

```
%% WORKING PART
%Preparing the gripper
gripper = tcpip('172.16.6.72',1000);
gripper.OutputBufferSize = 3000;
gripper.ByteOrder = 'littleEndian';
gripper.Timeout = 1;
fopen(gripper);

%Command
release = [170; 170; 170; 38; 8; 0; 0; 0; 160; 64; 0; 0; 210; 67; 0; 0];
release = hex2dec(release);
fwrite(gripper, uint8(release), 'uint8');
fclose(gripper);

%% NOT WORKING PART
readdata = fread(gripper,gripper.BytesAvailable);
```

If ´BytesAvailable´ is empty it absolutly makes sense, that this is not working. No Data no reading. My Question is it a problem with the gripper or  am I doing something totally wrong with the tcpip object configuration?

Comment: I would try to use native Java libraries instead. Java code can be embedded within Matlab code. For low level network communications, Java functions are usually better.

Comment: I doubt that `fread(gripper,...)` can succeed after the program has executed `fclose(gripper)`.  Try moving the `fclose` after the `fread`.